# View.Gone of ParentBottom view is causing issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have one photo application in which I am displaying admob banner on bottom of screen. I am managing it from java and hiding it sometime if required. Its working fine when I display ads like below

[image]

But when I hide banner....bottom navigation toolbar is going on top and screen showing blank like below

[image]

My XML is like below. Please check and help me for solve my issue. **bottom of xml with value ll_adLayout_latest is adview.** Thanks

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/image_back"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.karopass.karoshare.ImageDetails">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.example.utils.ExtendedViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_extended"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/pageNavCount"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
            android:background="@color/image_back"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pageNavCount"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/pageNavLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:id="@+id/new_time_count"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 Month ago"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center|start" />
            </RelativeLayout>







            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/new_share_count"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share_count"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="999"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center|start" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/new_save_count"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/like_count"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="999"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="#cccccc"
                    android:gravity="center|start" />
            </RelativeLayout>



        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/pageNavLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_adLayout_latest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/new_time"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_past_961"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>-->


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/new_copy"
                android:clickable="true"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_copy_96"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/new_save"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_save_96"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/new_share"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_share_96"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/new_fav"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_hearts_96"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"/>
            </RelativeLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_adLayout_latest"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have

```
<LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/pageNavLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_adLayout_latest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp">
```

Set to be above the `ll_adLayout_latest`, and when you make it `View.GONE`, layout will be re-examined as if `ll_adLayout_latest` is not in the layout at all.

You may do one of these two things (or both, depending on the behavior you finally need.).

1. Set your layout not to depend on `ll_adLayout_latest`'s position.
2. Instead of `View.GONE`, use `View.INVISIBLE`

When using `View.INVISIBLE`, the layout will not behave as if `ll_adLayout_latest` was never there, it will keep the dependencies you have stablished.